# iphone,objective c - Date comparison

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsdate

How to compare date in objective c. i have three date in nsstring format. Here i have to check whether a date is occurred inbetween or equal to two other dates. How to implement this any source code and tutorials, idea...?

here what i done so far...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/dd/MM"]; 

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:[State getIncurredDate]];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:startDate];
NSDate *date3 = [dateFormat dateFromString:endDate];
```

Comment: NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:startDate];                                  by doing this am getting NULL.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( [date isEqualToDate:otherDate] )
  NSLog(@"%@ is equal to %@",date,otherDate);
```

Done.

Comment: here am not getting isEqualToDate instead of that am getting isEqualToString.

Comment: If you just type isEqualToDate while ignoring the things xcode says you should be fine

Comment: NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:startDate]; by doing this am getting NULL ... dnt know y..

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dates into TimeInterval (since some reference date) and just compare numbers.

Comment: == re-implementing isEqualToDate

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
 
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/dd/MM"];                                     here how to set my date variable to date1 ...plse ref above... am new to iphone dev...
 
 NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
 NSDate *date2 = [date1 dateByAddingTimeInterval:(2 * 24 * 60 * 60)];
 
 if ( [date1 isEqualToDate: date2] ) {
  NSLog(@"equal");
 }